# How do I set up my fixtures for a has_and_belongs_to_many relation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, fixtures

I have the following models:

```
class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :regions

class Region < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requests
  has_and_belongs_to_many :companies

class RequestForProposals < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :region
```

Whenever I get a new request, I want to send a notification to the companies active in the same region.

How do I set this up in my fixtures so that I can unit test the logic of finding the right companies?

I've tried

```
region_ids: 1, 2
regions: one, two
```

in companies.yml, but neither works in assigning regions to the companies.

Here is a gist of the SQL generated: https://gist.github.com/2713518

Answer (score 41, accepted):

For

```
regions: one, two
```

in `companies.yml` to work you need to let rails auto assign the ids for the regions. This is because (in order to avoid having to have read regions.yml before companies.yml) rails calculates the ids it sticks in the join table from the names of the companies fixtures. if you've assigned the ids yourself, they won't match up with the calculated ones.

From the sql you've provided it looks like you're setting the ids on the regions to 1 and 2, i.e. your regions.yml has

```
one:
  id: 1
  name: MyString
```

Remove the `id:1` and you should be ok. You'll also need to update any other files (e.g. request_for_proposals.yml) that refer to regions, replacing

```
region_id: 1
```

with

```
region: one
```

Rails will know that means to set `region_id` to the id for the region with label `one` in your fixtures.

Answer (score 0):

Is your regions.yml in test/fixtures directory? How about companies.yml? Your code "regions: one, two", for a given company, should work.
Rails automatically loads the fixtures in this directory when you run the test.
If the locations are correct, please post the test output - sql generated - when you run the tests.

Comment: And yes, the fixtures files are in the test/fixtures directory

Answer (score 0):

In addition to accepted answer if you have a need to calculate such id by yourself, e.g. you have some loose references or another datasource just add:

```
def fixh(key)
  ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.identify key
end
```

to your `test_helper.rb` and then use this way in fixtures:

```
security_context1:
  ext_id: <%= fixh :user1 %>
```

Comment: Where would you recommend I put this `fixh(key)` method? I don't think I'm implementing this correctly.

Answer (score -1):

I'm unsure how does one use YAML fixtures these days. Have you tried [FactoryGirl](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) for creating db object instances while testing? It does pretty much the same as fixtures, in a much sophisticated way though.

The following passages assumes you are using `rspec` as a testing framework.

After including `factory_girl-rails` in your `Gemfile` and updating `spec/spec_helper.rb` accordingly to the `factory_girl`s README, create the following files:

```
# spec/factories/company_factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :company do
    title { |n| "Test Company #{n}" }

    # whatever else fields

    after_create { |company| company.regions << FactoryGirl.create(:region) }
  end
end

# spec/factories/region_factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :region do
    # whatever fields here
  end
end

# spec/factories/request_factories.rb
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :request do        
    # whatever fields here
  end
end
```

Now the real question is - what's the actual test code you're doing?